# Chrome extension - start point

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Where I can find an example code of chrome extension which shows the current address in a popup?

Thanks.
Ron

Comment: Please be more clear on what you mean by "current address in a popup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html
Samples: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html

This is the official documentation and sample code for Google Chrome extensions. In your [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) you want to declare a popup for either a page or browser action (whichever best suites your extension). In your popup HTML file you probably want something like the following;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initPopup() {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
                    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tab.url));
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initPopup();"></body>
</html>
```

This very simply appends the URL of the selected tab to the body of the popup.

Your manifest should look like the following;

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

The file structure for this example is a single folder containing `manifest.json`, `popup.html` and `icon.png`.

On the Extensions page (chrome://extensions) you should click *Load unpacked extension...* and navigate to this folder. If you make any changes to the manifest be sure to click the *Reload* link to pick up these changes.

I hope this helps but I strongly suggest reading through the documentation I mentioned above to get a better understanding of what you're doing.

**EDIT:** Added missing `null` argument to code and included an example manifest and file structure based on additional information gathered from comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get this error: No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-extension://hjmfkfilkpoggknobhhllgidfohljfph/popup.html
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

Comment: Could you show me the contents of your manifest and let me know your file structure?

Comment: {
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  }
}   file structure: the manifest and the popup.html are in the same dir and of course the icon.png file.

Comment: The error message is confusing but I can see from your manifest that you've used "popup" instead of "default_popup" in your "browser_action" declaration. Make that change and try again.

Comment: Still, same error: "Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found."

Comment: Chrome doesn't pick up all file changes for extensions dynamically (especially when changing the manifest) so have you tried removing the extensions and re-adding it. Sometimes a disable/enable cycle can fix this too.

Comment: ammm I tried it but still the same. But when i packed the extension i don't get an error in fact i get blank tiny popup. may be because it can't find popup.html file? BTW, thanks for your help

Comment: Please see the changes I've made to my answer and let me know how you get on. I've created a test extension for this and I get no problems. I make sure you add the fix for my popup.html code as well as the additional permissions declaration in the manifest.

Comment: No problem. That's a very strange solution. What made you think to do that? Are you able to accept my answer as it did answer your original question?

Comment: 1.  I thought maybe it'll will work. 2. Yes, already did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your popup, it works for me (Google Chrome 14-beta):

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(window.id, function(tab) {
        console.log(tab);
        console.log(tab.url); // url of the current tab
    });
});
```

For more information check: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected

Comment: You only need to provide a `null` as the window ID argument for `chrome.tabs.getSelected` since it defaults to the current window (as mentioned in the very same link you provided).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all these answers are outdated so here is a manifest 2 example. You will need jQuery for this example. I have included all the files in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Christianjuth/49a6531b1245770afc30).

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "1.0",

  "author": "Christian Juth",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <span id="address"></span>

  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //define query
  var query = { active: true, currentWindow: true };

  //query tabs
  chrome.tabs.query(query, function (tabs) {
    currentAddress = tabs[0].url;
    $('#address').text(currentAddress);
  });

});
```

Comment: Valiant attempt, but downvoting since it shows the wrong address (the address of the popup itself, and not the current tab).

Comment: I do agree that a `"manifest_version" : 2` answer is needed. Hope you'll edit it into shape.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. It should work now.

Comment: Good, it's improving. But `tabs.getSelected` is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to StackOverflow and my answer was a little sloppy. It should be fixed now and up to date.

Comment: Argh. Sorry, still wrong! I quote the [`setSelected` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected): _Deprecated since Chrome 33. Please use `tabs.query {active: true}`._ Also I recommend using `currentWindow: true`. Sorry for treating the answer harshly, but since the point of this answer is to update to new API, it must be 100% correct and up to date.

Comment: Okay then. A final improvement would be to replace `"tabs"` permission with a much less scary [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).